# Route model binding with relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
PUT|PATCH       api/v1/tweets/{tweet}/comments/{comment} tweets.comments.update › Api\\V1\\TweetCommentController@update
```

i've this above route, and i'm trying to bind the relationship from controller

I'm passing formadata with key *`comment = This is a test comment`*

I tried this code below in TweetCommentController.

```
public function update(Tweet $tweet, TweetComment $comment, TweetCommentRequest $request)
```

but this is not working. it just redirect to the login page.

I also tried this below too

```
public function update(Tweet $tweet, TweetComment $comment)
```

This one seems working, atleast i'm able to log $tweet and $comment., but i cannot access the form data.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake,
I tried the api call from postman, and i used method PUT.

I changed the method to POST and add a new key `_method = PUT` in form data

so, my current (working) code looks like this

### API call

POST {{base_url}}/tweets/1/comments/2

form-data :
comment = "edited test comment"
_method = PUT

### Controller

```
public function update(TweetCommentRequest $request, Tweet $tweet, TweetComment $comment){
    $comment->update($request->validated());
    return $this->sendResponse([
            'message' => __('Comment updated successfully.'),
            'comment' => $comment
        ]);
}
```